# Place cursor at the end of text in an iframe body element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'll start by apologising as this may seem like or actually be a duplicate, but I've tried every solution I've encountered and none seem to be working for me.

In my HTML I have an iframe referencing another HTML document. With JavaScript, at the press of a list of buttons I insert text into the body of that iframe. I also use JavaScript to maintain focus on the iframe body. The problem is that nothing appears to work for me to get the cursor to move to the end of the text each time I press those buttons, it always moves to the beginning.

One of the solutions I've tried was to add this code to the function that handles my button presses:

```
iFrameBody.focus();
var content = iFrameBody.innerHTML;
iFrameBody.innerHTML = content;
```

so the function looks like this:

```
function typeIn(buttonId) {

    var iFrameBody = document.getElementById("iFrame").contentWindow.document.body;
    iFrameBody.innerHTML += buttonId;

    iFrameBody.focus();
    var content = iFrameBody.innerHTML;
    iFrameBody.innerHTML = content;
}
```

Something else I tried was, in the HTML file referenced by my iframe I did:

```
<body onfocus="this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;"></body>
```

I tried several other more complicated solutions that frankly I didn't even quite understand to be honest, all to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible for you to put it in a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at the question. The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrtpda1f/1/) is here, I don't know how helpful it will be since I couldn't figure out how to add the referenced iframe html file. Still, any thoughts on a possible resolution for this issue?? I still haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: see is this f any help to you : http://www.sitepoint.com/jqueryhtml5-input-focus-cursor-positions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was that I was using a body element, writing to it's innerHTML and trying to set focus on the body.  By simply using a textarea inside my iFrame instead it became very simple and it only required the simplest code.

This to set focus when the page loads:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var iFrameTextArea = document.getElementById("iFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("iFrameTextArea");
    iFrameTextArea.focus();
}
```

And then this to set the button to write to the textarea while maintaining focus:

```
function typeIn(buttonId) {

    var iFrameTextArea = document.getElementById("iFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("iFrameInput");

    iFrameTextArea.focus();

    iFrameTextArea.value += buttonId;

}
```

Super easy!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of again using textarea in iframe, u can also solve this by using the following code.

```
var iframeElement = document.getElementById("iFrame").contentWindow.document.body;
            iframeElement.focus();
            var len = iframeElement.length ;
            iframeElement.setSelectionRange(len, len);
```